# Automatically dim the backlight of a secondary monitor on MAC

Tags: osx, display-settings

I have a 2010 iMac 27" as well as a 27" Apple Cinema Display. The iMac will auto-dim on inactivity, I'd say around 5 minutes. When the iMac dim's the Cinema Display is still bright. There is no "Automatically reduce the brightness of the display" option in Energy Saver or Displays within System Preferences. Anyone any suggestions?

CLI commands would be preferred.

Comment: This probably belongs on [http://apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Yes it does. At first I saw ask dif and was like wtf is that, that's not what I want. They should have just calle it Mac or apple :p

Answer (score 3):

For the Apple displays most of the tighter controls goes through USB - do you have the cable going from the display to the iMac?

Under display preferences do you see a checkbox for automatic ambient control, or for keyboard controls depending on versions.  Try toggling these checkbox(es) and see if that affects the auto-dim.

Last but not least, ensure the dim buttons on your keyboard affect both main screen and the cinema display.

Awhile ago others had similar issues

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2649213?start=0&tstart=0